# At which end of the scale on the knob is the refrigerator temperature lowest, at which is it highest?

Tags: refrigerator

At what point the temperature of refrigerator/frig going high or low ?                        For example the numbers are given 1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 some people set at 5 or some people set at 1 at which figure temperature is high or low?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that there is a worldwide standard for all refrigerators. After all, it is just numbers painted on a knob, every manufacturer can paint there whatever they please.

You have to measure the temperature to know exactly where you get the optimal 4 Celsius. But even without measuring, you can leave it for a few hours at one end and you will notice if it is too cold or too warm.

Alternatively, just look up the user manual.

Comment: Consensus seems to indicate that fridge settings are unreliable anyway, and you ought to go by temperature instead: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4529/what-temperatures-should-i-keep-my-refrigerator-and-freezer-set-at?rq=1