# How to store batter (contains raw eggs) under 41 degrees F?

Tags: baking, food-safety, storage-method, eggs, storage-lifetime

We had a food inspector come by today and they had recommend that we store our batter (contains raw eggs) in an ice bucket at 41ºF (5ºC) or below at all times.

I feel that this process is a bit tedious and feel that there's another way. How do most establishments store their batter? Are there equipment that can satisfy these requirements?

Comment: What temperature is your fridge? Are you asking about long term storage or just what you'd use in a shift?

Comment: Not enough information to answer the question. A recommendation will be citation next time so start with some ice. He may come back tomorrow.  Why is a question this unclear getting up voted?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [this answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/4544/47457) for a somewhat related question:

> The ideal refrigerator temperature is 35°F (1.6°C). You're not hugging the danger zone like you would be at 40°F (4.4°C), and you're distancing yourself sufficiently from 32°F (0°C) that you don't freeze half the stuff in your refrigerator. That said, the temperature within your fridge can vary rather significantly with normal usage.

The reason for the quote is that most domestic refrigerators are able to be set to a temperature of less than 40ºF. As you are not talking about domestic but it sounds more industrial/professional, I doubt you would have a refrigerator that can't store at a temperature below this.

Therefore I would imagine storing it in the fridge would be fine and more convenient than the ice bucket suggested.

However the temperature within different areas of the fridge can vary depending on how frequently it is accessed (which is why you shouldn't keep [eggs](http://www.eggs.ca/eggs101/view/39/egg-storage-freshness-and-food-safety) or other easily spoilable foods in the fridge door) so this could potentially be a problem depending on your exact situation, how frequently it is opened and where in the fridge you keep the batter.

Comment: Pretty sure this is container in a cooks station and the under fridge is not big enough.

Comment: @Paparazzi Ah ok, in that case my answer isn't ideal - the question doesn't give an indication as to scale/volume.

Comment: I did not down vote you down and the question is not clear.   It is the only thing that makes sense to me for the inspector to say ice.

Comment: @Paparazzi I know you didn't down vote - I appreciate it thanks :) I have no experience of health inspectors or professional equipment so just went with what I know to try and answer. I'm perfectly happy to up-vote a more suitable answer (and ask for further clarification before answering future questions if necessary)

Comment: Answer as many questions as you like.  Don't base protocol on me.  I get down voted a lot and questioned by mods.

Comment: @Paparazzi As do I on other stackexchanges... lol